# How can I set theme for custom toast layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-toast

I need to set transparent theme for my custom toast layout. But with the code below this does not happen. Maybe I do it with the wrong context?!

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    LinearLayout linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.toast_layout);

   Context context = getApplicationContext();
    context.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Transparent);
    View layout = inflater.cloneInContext(context).inflate(R.layout.info_layout,
            linearLayout);

    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Create the view and apply the theme to the top level parent then apply that as the custom view for the toast.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using cloneInContext? You can simply do as follows. It works in my code

```
Toast toast = new Toast(context);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
toast.setView(view);
toast.show();
```

You can create a custom layout and set the theme inside it to AppTheme_Transparent.

Comment: @AndrewEfremov getContext()? It's inherited from activity.